# How to load and manipulate an HTML fragment from a string with Cheerio?

Tags: javascript, parsing, dom, cheerio

I'm struggling trying to load an HTML fragment with Cheerio.

```
var htmlString = '<div class="artist"><i class="user blue circle icon"></i> Skyy</div>';
var $ = cheerio.load(data);
console.info($.html());
```

Outputs

```
<html><head></head><body><div class="artist"><i class="user blue circle icon"></i> Skyy</div></body></html>
```

My problem is, I think, that Cheerio wraps my content within an HTML document, which makes it difficult to access the node directly.

I could eventually use this selector, it works pretty fine:

```
var el = $('body').children().first();
```

But it doesn't always work. For instance,

```
var htmlString = '<meta name="description" content="My description">';
var $ = cheerio.load(data);
console.info($.html());
```

Will output a different kind of document, where `var el = $('body').children().first();` will not work:

```
<html><head><meta name="description" content="My description"></head><body></body></html>
```

So, is there a way to load an HTML fragment and to access it as a Cheerio element without using a selector?

I want to be able to use the Cheerio functions like `.text()`, `.html()` or `.attr()`, on the populated node.

Comment: So what exactly is the output you want?

Comment: either the node text, or an attribute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76240362/6243352) offers a great start, but it doesn't show a consistent way to access the tag.

`$(":root").first();` seems like a good approach to extract the first tag, not extensively tested but looks promising on a spot check.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12
const {strict: assert} = require("node:assert");

const loadOneTag = html => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(html, null, /*isDocument=*/false);
  assert.equal($.html(), html);
  return $(":root").first();
};

{
  // one top-level child
  const html = `
    <div class="artist"><i class="user blue circle icon"></i> Skyy</div>
  `;
  assert.equal(loadOneTag(html).attr("class"), "artist");
}

{
  // multiple top-level children
  const html = `
    <div class="artist"><i class="user blue circle icon"></i> Skyy</div>
    <p>asdf</p>
  `;
  assert.equal(loadOneTag(html).attr("class"), "artist");
}

{
  // meta tag
  const html = `
    <meta name="description" content="My description">
  `;
  assert.equal(loadOneTag(html).attr("name"), "description");
}
```

Comment: Seems to work ! Except that, according to TypeScript, `cheerio.load`'s second argument should be `undefined` rather than `null`.

Comment: Thanks, and feel free to sub it in if you want, but the [source code seems to show `null`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/37fdde71931b61a5c13a4bd007572accff599e8a/src/load.ts#L128), which is sort of the standard for ("skip this param") in most APIs I've seen. They should put `isDocument` into the options argument. It's not really readable otherwise. It's probably a backwards-compatibility thing. But I digress...

Comment: Typescript fires an error with null, they want it undefined (or defined).  But maybe their types are not good.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in cheerio to disable wrapping your html in other tags, the *third* argument (the second takes an object containing additional options; we can set it to null) of `cheerio.load`:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(htmlString, null, false)
console.log($.html()) // <-- just the html, not wrapped
```

You can view [the source](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/main/src/load.ts#L129) for more info.

Comment: using last Cheerio version (^1.0.0-rc.12), it gives me `TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.`.

Comment: @gordie I just tried it and it works. Are you sure there isn't something else interfering?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript ?

Comment: @gordie no; I guess it's an issue with TS then. What version of `@types/cheerio` are you using?

Comment: types are ^0.22.31

Comment: @gordie apparently the lib is out of date (the definition doesn't include the third argument). I guess you just have TS ignore that line? https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cheerio/index.d.ts#L322

Comment: Ok, I hacked the types file ! It works !
Then how would you access an attribute from the populated string ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.

By loading a blank document, I can add my html string manually to it - so i'm sure it will be in the `<body/>`, even if it's a meta element that Cheerio would normally load in the `<head/>`.

```
var $ = cheerio.load('');
$('body').append(htmlString);
var el = $('body').children().first();
```